# How to scrape this using bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have to get `<a class="last" aria-label="Last Page" href="https://webtoon-tr.com/webtoon/page/122/">Son »</a>`.
From this site:https://webtoon-tr.com/webtoon/

But when i try to scrape it with this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://webtoon-tr.com/webtoon/"
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

last = soup.find_all("a",{"class":"last"})
print(last)
```

It just returns me an empty list, and when i try to scrape all "a" tags it only returns 2 which are completly different things.

Can somebody help me about it ? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website is protected by Cloudflare. requests, cloudscraper or request_html doesn't work for me, only selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://webtoon-tr.com/webtoon/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html5lib')
browser.quit()
link = soup.select_one('a.last')
print(link)
```

This returns

```
<a aria-label="Last Page" class="last" href="https://webtoon-tr.com/webtoon/page/122/">Son »</a>
```

Comment: I had couple more websites to scrap and neither of the requests worked , this fixes it but i dont quite know selenium . Can you basicly explain the logic and the stuff in terminal , thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Selenium is a library which is using an actual browser to access the page. Beside (pip) installing the library, you need to also download the chromedriver binary depending on your OS< and the version of Chrome installed on your system. You can also use Firefox (with a different binary and set of commands though). You want me to explain the imports, or ... I don't really get it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the request_html library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests_html

url = "https://webtoon-tr.com/webtoon/"

s = requests_html.HTMLSession()

html = s.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "lxml")

last = soup.findAll("a", {"class":"last"})
print(last)
```

```
[<a aria-label="Last Page" class="last" href="https://webtoon-tr.com/webtoon/page/122/">Son »</a>]
```

Comment: **Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*